# Symfony2 collection of entities, add new from select

Tags: symfony, select, collections, prototype, entities

I am starting with Symfony2, excuse me if my question is very easy but:

I have 2 entities:

News (id, title, tags)

Tag (id, news)

I have relations many-to-many

Sample code of News:

```
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"}))
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_tags")
  */
  private $tags;
```

Sample code of Tag:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="tags")
 */
 private $news;
```

I have a TagType to adding tags to DB, just simple

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name', 'text');
}
```

NewsType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('title', 'text', array(
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'maxlength'=>60
                    )
                ))
                ->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                    'type'=>new TagType(),
                    'allow_add'=>true,
                    'allow_delete'=>true,
                    'by_reference'=>false,
                ))
        ;
    }
```

Sample of News form HTML:

```
<table class="tags table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'XAdminBundle:Form:news_tags_prototype.html.twig' with {'form': form.tags.vars.prototype} %}{% endfilter %}">
                {% for tag in form.tags %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ tag.vars.data.name }}
                            {{ form_widget(tag.name, {'attr': {'class': 'hidden'} }) }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="action">                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

news_tags_prototype.html.twig

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' } }) }}</td>
    <td class="action"></td>
</tr>
```

In this case when I click Add Tag, I've got a text input and I can add completely new tag, but the only one I want after click Add Tag get a select box with names of Tag entitiess from DB.
How to do this throw js and prototype (suggested by http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In TagType, you should go with something like:

```
$builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'SomeBundle:Tag'));
```

Which will ensure that the prototype renders as a dropdown instead of a text element. Hope that helps.

Edit: I just realized that you probably need your existing TagType in order to add the tag to the database in the first place. In that case, create a new file called TagDropdownType with my suggested change above and then in your NewsType, change:

```
->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                'type'=>new TagType(),
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'by_reference'=>false,
            ))
```

to:

```
->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                'type'=>new TagDropdownType(),
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'by_reference'=>false,
            ))
```